# Using a profile with custom fields for event online registration

Tags: civicrm-event

new to CiviCRM.  Have set up a profile that I would like to use for online event registration.  It looks very ugly and I was wondering if there was a way to make it look better?  I'm using a mixture of text boxes (they look ok) and some questions have radio buttons and check boxes.  It's the radio button and check box questions that look very cluttered.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Drupal, I highly recommend Webform CiviCRM Integration module for this. You can use custom profiles with this and make it all look great.

Comment: It would help folk if you told them more about your set up - what CMS - what theme extensions are you using in civicrm - what theme for the CMS. if these seem scary questions then just ask me to explain further

Answer (score 1):

Try a theme for CiviCRM, like [Shoreditch](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch).